# Formatted count by topic

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, jquery, usage-counters

I have been searching for days and I have been unable to figure out if my wish is possible.

I have a large list that contains an inventory of active items being utilized, with each item having an associated column titled `Topic`.

I was wondering if it is possible to use a `CEWP` to display a color-banded table that provides a count for each topic.

Unfortunately, I can not use the lookup column trick due to various data connection issues, so I am hoping there may be a solution using JQuery, JavaScript or HTML.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.